# Select count with left join counting from both tables

Tags: mysql, select, count, left-join

I have the following query:

```
select count(*) as `count`, ass.date_assigned as date_assigned
from `buyers` as b
left join `assignments` as ass on (ass.id_buyer = b.id)
```

I only want this to count the total `buyers`. The problem is it appears to be counting all of the `assignments` as well.

I've tried grouping by `b.id` and `ass.id_buyer`, I've tried changing `count(*)` to `count(b.id)`.

Nothing works. How do I fix this so it only counts the `buyers`?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)` maybe?

Comment: select count(*) as `count`
from `buyers` as b

Comment: You need an aggregation function around `ass.date_assigned`. Otherwise it will just pick a random date from the join.

Comment: show the raw data in your table and expected result recordset please

Comment: If you use `LEFT JOIN`, it will also count buyers who have no assignments. Why are you using this instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Hey @daygloink. What happened to your question "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','" ?? Why you deleted. ? What was the answer ?

Comment: The answer was a google maps code have an empty latitude and longitude causing an invalid comma in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS count, MAX(a.date_assigned) AS last_date_assigned
FROM buyers AS b
INNER JOIN assignments AS a ON a.id_buyer = b.id
```

I've also changed from `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` so that it will only count buyers who have assignments (otherwise why join with `assignments`?). And used `MAX(a.date_assigned)` so that it selects a particular assignment date, not just a random date from any of the assignments.

Comment: I left join assignments because I want to include buyers with no assignments. Thank you for the distinct tip :)

Comment: If you want buyers with no assignments, why do you need to join with the assignments table at all?

Comment: Just use `select count(*) from buyers`.

Comment: Because I have a custom filter which allows the user to filter the results by having assignments and not having assignments. Therefore it is necessary to have this in the query so it can be standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Use right Outer Join:

```
select count(*) as `count`, ass.date_assigned as date_assigned from `buyers` as b right outer join `assignments` as ass on (ass.id_buyer = b.id)
```

Comment: That will still multiply by all the assignments.